# Plausibility of Eurojackpot lottery - looping through large arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, math, probability

Last Friday I did not win anything in Eurojackpot lottery again. I was thinking about the plausibility of the winners list they publish after the lottery draw. So I wrote a little script to check how the distribution of winning players could be.

You see in the script below one randomly generated draw and how many players (also randomly generated tips) match that in anyway.

For those who don't know about the game rules: You pick 5 of 50 (1-50) main numbers and 2 of 10 (1-10) side numbers. The lottery does the same. To get the jackpot you have to hit all their main and side numbers.

I put the amount of players to 1000. WARNING: Increase this number to let's say 1.000.000 and you will feel the `for` loops working. Be careful and increase it slowly (10.000, 100.000, 500.000, ...)

An example in array notation:

```
lotteries maindraw = [12, 31, 35, 46, 48], sidedraw = [2, 8]

palyer tip [12, 31, 35, 46, 5], [2, 4] = 4 + 1 (4 equals in main, 1 equal in side)
palyer tip [31, 4, 35, 11, 17], [9, 5] = 2 + 0
and so on ...
```

MY TWO QUESTIONS!

First the script: How can I optimize it, so 100.000.000 players won't hang the browser? You see a `for` loop and inside of it `filter` and `indexOf`. Is there a better way to loop faster and go easy on memory?

Second maybe offtopic! I hit the play button many many times, never got a jackpot winner (5 + 2). Is there something wrong with my script or is the probability really so hard? (Eurojackpot faking me?)

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector('.players button').addEventListener('click', lottery)
};

function lottery() {

    // clean board
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function (e) {
        e.remove();
    });

    var playerCount = document.querySelector('.players input').value || 10000;
    var realtimecounts = true;

    var mainDrawCount = 5;
    var mainDrawRange = 50;
    var mainDrawResult = [];

    var sideDrawCount = 2;
    var sideDrawRange = 10;
    var sideDrawResult = 0;

    var winners = [];

    // random draw helper (returns an array with random numbers)
    var randomDraw = function (count, range) {
        var result = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + 1);
            if (result.indexOf(randomNumber) > -1) {
                // prevent double numbers in result
                x--;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                result.push(randomNumber);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // get mainDrawResult
    mainDrawResult = randomDraw(mainDrawCount, mainDrawRange);

    // write down mainDrawResult
    document.querySelector('.maindraw-result').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>' + mainDrawResult.join(', ') + '</span>');

    // get sideDrawResult
    sideDrawResult = randomDraw(sideDrawCount, sideDrawRange);

    // write down sideDrawResult
    document.querySelector('.sidedraw-result').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>' + sideDrawResult.join(', ') + '</span>');

    // let's look for winners
    for (var x = 0; x < playerCount; x++) {
        // get player tips
        var playerMainTip = randomDraw(mainDrawCount, mainDrawRange);
        var playerSideTip = randomDraw(sideDrawCount, sideDrawRange);

        // check player tips
        var playerMainTipCompare = mainDrawResult.filter(function (e) {
            return playerMainTip.indexOf(e) > -1;
        });
        var playerSideTipCompare = sideDrawResult.filter(function (e) {
            return playerSideTip.indexOf(e) > -1;
        });

        // add or count up winning type
        if (typeof winners['winners-' + playerMainTipCompare.length + '-' + playerSideTipCompare.length] !== 'undefined')
            ++winners['winners-' + playerMainTipCompare.length + '-' + playerSideTipCompare.length];
        else
            winners['winners-' + playerMainTipCompare.length + '-' + playerSideTipCompare.length] = 1;
    }

    // write winners down
    for (var key in winners)
        document.querySelector('.' + key).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>' + winners[key] + ' x</span>');
}
```

```css
.wrap {
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 280px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.wrap div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrap div:not(.players):not(.sidedraw-result) {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>lottery check</h1>
    <div class="players"><label>players: </label><input type="text" value="10000" size="10"><button>play</button></div>
    <hr>
    <h2>draws</h2>
    <div class="maindraw-result"><label>main (5 of 50): </label></div>
    <div class="sidedraw-result"><label>side (2 of 10): </label></div>
    <hr>
    <h2>winners</h2>
    <div class="winners-5-2"><label>5 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-5-1"><label>5 + 1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-5-0"><label>5 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-4-2"><label>4 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-4-1"><label>4 + 1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-4-0"><label>4 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-3-2"><label>3 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-3-1"><label>3 + 1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-3-0"><label>3 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-2-2"><label>2 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-2-1"><label>2 + 1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-2-0"><label>2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-1-2"><label>1 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-1-1"><label>1 + 1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-1-0"><label>1 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-0-2"><label>0 + 2 </label></div>
    <div class="winners-0-1"><label>0 + 1</label></div>
    <div class="winners-0-0"><label>0 </label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: to answer your second question: winning chances: `1:95.344.200`. So it would be kind of a miracle if you've hit the winning result by some (hundrets of) button clicks

Comment: Hitting the button a few hundret times was very experienced. So you think there is probably no mistake?

Comment: as long as you have not clicked that button for about **100.000.000** times it would be very lucky to hit the correct numbers. Even if you tried it for more than 100.000.000 times it **must not** hit the correct numbers. Of course there is a chance (of 1:95.344.200) to get the win on the first try but as you can see the chance is very small. In other words: If about 100 millions of the europeans played that lottery there should be propably only one single winner